# Стоит ли использовать HP NC362i под большой нагрузкой?

Tags: сеть, железо

Из даташита следует что в DL160 G6\DL165 G7 встроена двух портовая сетевая карта HP NC362i на Intel 82576. У меня есть HP Proliant SE316M1 (aka DL160 G6, но только SE). Поставил Intel E1G42ET. Хочу объединить в link aggregation порты как у встроенной сетевой карты так и у Intel E1G42ET и использовать его как софт роутер. Нагрузка будет большая (для меня)): ~2Gbps на 300Kpps. Стоит ли использовать встроенную сетевую карту или лучше докупить еще одну intel E1G42ET? Поставил бы что-нибудь на Intel 82599 но некуда пока воткнуть (в светлом будущем так и сделаю)).

Answer (score 2):

В принципе чип один и агрегировать их можно, но тогда лучше поставить драйвер от Intel а не вендорский, если верить документу, 300Kpps потянет, на больших пакетах они до 1,5Mpps дотягивают, в жизни получается около 600Kpps на UDP